# seeking to relate to others

Tags: descriptive-grammar

I am looking to for a word that describes a person who often seeks to relate to others. He looks to include outsiders into groups and is able to adjust speech depending on who he is talking to.

Comment: With what motive? Such a person could be *friendly, considerate, manipulative, polite*, for example.

Comment: Someone who is able to relate to widely different types of people, I would describe as *democratic*. But that may be a partly of my own coinage. Others may have different ways of saying it.

Comment: 'describes a person' could mean that you want a noun or an adjective. Please can you say which you are asking for? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Cordial** may fit.

> Definition: courteous and gracious; friendly; warm; easy
>   to talk to.

Synonym: **affable**

Answer (score 0):

How about welcoming as the adjective?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Can you provide some more details to support your suggestion - perhaps a cited definition, or a reputable example of it being used in a relevant way?